# Regex to match three forms of dates

Tags: regex, string, date

I have dates in these three formats, even though they are all mm/dd/yy

`11/12/2014  (\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})`  Right matches the date on the left

`11/2/2014   (\d{2})\/(\d{1})\/(\d{4})`  Right matches the date on the left

`5/12/2014   (\d{1})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})` This however doesn't match the date on the left, it rather matches  the first date, but except the first '1'. so it matches 1`1/12/2014`

I want to match the date pattern where the number before first '/' is always one digit like this:
`7`/12/2014 (which is July, 12 2014) and is in mm/dd/yy format

Comment: What's your question, you already have a regex for that 5/12/2014   `(\d{1})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}` ? A regex matches what you want it to. It matches nothing else ! There is _NO_ way it will ever match `11/12/2014`

Comment: If you don't want surrounding digits within the text string, use `^$` anchors, or assertions.

Comment: Sure that a regex will match what you want it to @SariksaThapa ? Its a certainty. Example `\d{2}` always will match two digits and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4}) matches all 3.
```

http://regex101.com/r/hT8wS4/1

### Update

"I want something to only match the third one.. and not match the first or the second one, even partially."

Use this negative lookahead:

```
(?<!\d)(\d)\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})
```

http://regex101.com/r/hT8wS4/4

This also excludes the form `m/d/yyyy` as requested, because the day is specified as having to be 2 digits.

Comment: I want regex to only match a date in the m/dd/yyyy format. It shouldn't match mm/dd/yyyy or m/d/yyyy or mm/d/yyyy

Comment: I'm very confused about what you want. Can you list some examples of dates and the desired results?

Comment: in your example, change your regex to this: (\d{1})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4}), you will see that it will completely match the last one, and partially match the first and second dates too!! I want something to only match the third one.. and not match the first or the second one, even partially..

Comment: Great! One more thing, do you want it to match dates like this, or exclude them? 5/2/2014

Comment: Exclude that format too, if possible? Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. `(?<!\d)(\d)\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})` excludes that format too. Updated answer again.

Comment: It's still matching both the third and the fourth, I meant to only match the fourth one only

Comment: (?<!\d)(\d)\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}) finally isolates the date format to just m/dd/yyyy  .... Thank you so much!!!

Comment: How did you add a code snippet in your previous comment? Ctrl - K??

Comment: Surround the text with backticks: `  See this reference: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: `(?<!\d)(\d)\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})` finally isolates the date format to just m/dd/yyyy. Got it! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}
```

That should get ALL of your form of dates...

If you want it to NOT get double digit months, then use this:

```
(?<!\d)\d{1}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}
```

To only match the third one:

```
(?<!\d)\d{1}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}
```

Comment: Still not working. (\d{1})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}) matches 1/12/2014 even on this date (11/12/2014), and doesn't match 5/12/2014